keras and tensorflow for R: warnings tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated and flushing python buffers sys.stderr and sys.stdout
How can I get rid of these warnings? They appear each time I start a new session and enter the commands:
library(keras)
m = keras_model_sequential()

I get the following warnings:

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\liuli\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.


WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\liuli\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py:873: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.


Warning messages:
1: In py_run_string_impl(patch, local = TRUE) : Error encountered when flushing python buffers sys.stderr and sys.stdout
2: In py_run_string_impl(patch, local = TRUE) : Error encountered when flushing python buffers sys.stderr and sys.stdout
3: In py_run_string_impl("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '')", local = TRUE) : Error encountered when flushing python buffers sys.stderr and sys.stdout

I tried to reinstall keras and tensorflow packages many times.
